# Allowing all users on the machine to use azure vpn connection?

Tags: vpn, azure

I have a point-to-site VPN connection to an azure network. 
It's set up by the localadmin on the computer and only works as long as he is logged in and opened the connection. However, if another user logs in without the localadmin logged in in parallel, the connection is not available. I want the connection to always be available to open for any user on that machine.

The VPN is set up using the [standard azure installation method for point-to-site VPNs](https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-point-to-site-create/). It includes downloading a "vpn package" executable which does the setup. There is not much to configure.

When I run this executable as the admin, a vpn adapter is set up using the certificates I imported into the local certificate store. When I run the setup as a restricted user, it requires me to enter the admins credentials and then silently quits doing nothing. No adapter is set up. The certificates are created like described in the tutorial linked above, there is no username in the certificate, just the computers name. Also, there is nothing in the event log when the installation fails like this.

Comment: Why not save the trouble and create a site-to-site connection instead?

Comment: @Noor Because we have many users working from customer sites or from home, not from a central company site.

Comment: This should help? http://blogs.technet.com/b/networking/archive/2013/10/02/automatically-triggering-vpn-connections-and-vpn-diagnostics-enhancements-in-windows-8-1.aspx

Comment: @Noor: Thanks, but my Win7 doesn't seem to have any [Add-VPN*](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn296460.aspx)-cmdlets in Powershell. I will try again after I upgraded to Powershell 4.

Comment: @Noor: Still no luck, does not seem to work on Win7, there are no Add-VPN*-cmdlets in [Powershell 4 for Win7](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/21016.how-to-install-windows-powershell-4-0.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the installation of the vpn-package from azure only works for admin users. It does not work for unpriviledged (domain) users when executed with admin rights.

To enable the vpn-connection for domain users without having a local admin logged on in parallel, the domain user has to be given local admin rights. This is done by the local admin by adding the domain user to the machines "Administrators"-group (this is not the domains administrators group). After this, re-logon as the domain user which is now a local admin and retry to install the vpn-package. It should work. The vpn-connection is now visible in the network and sharing center and ready to use.

It seems, this has to be done for every user of the machine who needs to use the connection.